# Storing favourite item from list into a SharedPreferences in android?

Tags: java, android

I am calling list of items from Firebase firestore. and setting it into a recycle-view. and I have implemented functionality of saving item as favorite by storing its position into array list of Shared-preferences. But the issue I was facing is: 
Suppose there are 5 items in recyclerview. and I have liked 3 of its items. and I destroyed my app. when I again open my app I like one more item and then again destroyed my app. after that when I open my app again there is like only on last time which I liked. previous 3 items liked gone. I am not understanding why its happening. 
*Note: Till now I didn't added functionality of removing like from my item list.

Below is my logical code:

Shared-preferences Model

```
public class SharedPref {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;
    public SharedPref(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        preferences =context.getSharedPreferences("Stackoverflow", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor =preferences.edit();
    }

    public  boolean putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public  boolean getBoolean(String key) {
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    }
    public  boolean putString(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }
    public String getString(String key) {
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }

    public  boolean putLong(String key, long value) {
        editor.putLong(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public  long getLong(String key) {
        return preferences.getLong(key, 0);
    }

    public  boolean putInt(String key, int value) {
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }
    public  int getInt(String key) {
        return preferences.getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public  boolean putFloat(String key, float value) {
        editor.putFloat(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }
    public  float getFloat(String key) {
        return preferences.getFloat(key, 0);
    }
    public boolean remove(String key){
        return editor.remove(key).commit();
    }
    public boolean clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return editor.clear().commit();
    }

    public void putListString(String key, ArrayList<String> stringList) {
        checkForNullKey(key);
        String[] myStringList = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
        preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("‚‗‚", myStringList)).apply();
    }

    public void checkForNullKey(String key){
        if (key == null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListString(String key) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚")));
    }
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
Boolean favimageclick=true;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    ArrayList<String> favlist=new ArrayList<>();

if (sharedPref.getListString("fav")!=null)
        {
            Log.e("StoredData","______"+sharedPref.getListString("fav"));
            for(String data:sharedPref.getListString("fav"))
            {
                if (data.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(position))) {
                    holder.imageViewFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                }
            }
        }

        holder.imageViewFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (favimageclick) {
                    holder.imageViewFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                    favlist.add(String.valueOf(position));
                    sharedPref.putListString("fav",favlist);
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading favorites you only set changes to the view but do not put it to `favlist`. Next time when you add another item to favorites you put it to `favlist` but it contains only this one thing. And after that you save this one-item list to shared prefs overwriting what was there before.

When you load data from shared prefs put it to `favlist`.

Btw., unless your list is always built using the same data in the same order, storing position in favorites will cause issues.